# How does this work: http://welbog.homeip.net/

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

How does this work?: http://welbog.homeip.net/

Just scroll down. It looks cool, it looks damn cool, and it works without javascript. What's that?

Comment: do you mean that when you scroll down it automatically 'extends' ? please give some more information about your question :)

Comment: This is the semi-transparent png they use to shine the images through: http://welbog.homeip.net/glue/images/gradient.png. You can fetch such information from an average DOM inspector in fact.

Comment: @Karel you try to explain it in words then. "scroll down and it automatically 'extends' " doesn't make much sense

Comment: I was just wondering if that was what you meant, or if I was missing something else. don't have to be a jerk about Just trying to help >.>

Comment: @Karel i'm curious how is my above comment offensive unless you already feel defensive in the first place. why would i be offensive to a comment ending with a smiley? my first sentence means then you try to explain it in words. the second sentence means i couldn't make sense of your first comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's made by the divs having a fixed background that doesn't scroll with it and is very tall.

You can see here in the CSS:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right top;
```

This will keep it attached to the top-right, never repeat it and make it appear "fixed" to the site.

Each div has a different background to give this effect.

Comment: Yes, and that's the reason why it's loading awfully long

Comment: Absolutely right, there.

Comment: that css is actually for the feathering effect on the fixed background. The fixed image css is on the div that wraps div.window

Comment: Either way, it does the same thing.

Comment: no, the css you have repeats an image horizontally. That's responsible for the bottom border, not the fixed image

Comment: @Shiznit omg you're right.. Reading the wrong part AGAIN today.. I thin I need coffee.. Thanks :) Edited now.

Answer (score 2):

It is fixed background, and every element(paragraph) has it

Answer (score 0):

```
background-attachment: fixed
```

plus some css expression magic for older versions of ie